# How to user 2 condition in an select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want that select name and family of user in a table that User-Id (in this)
is FK in another table. my conditions are:
1.[User-Id](in this table) = [Resume-Owner-Id] in other table.
2.Row number is between 2 value that get from asp program.
I write below code. but this has error.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT Family,
               Name,
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   ORDER BY [User-Id] DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM   [Members-Description-Tbl]) AS People
WHERE  [User-Id] = (SELECT [Resume-Owner-Id]
                    FROM   [Resume-Tbl])
       AND ( RowNum BETWEEN @StartRowIndex + 1 AND @MaxRows );
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: say: Invalid column name 'User-Id'. but this column is valid.

Comment: Problem is u missed to select 'User-Id' in inner query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
Select *
From (select Family, Name,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [User-Id] desc) AS RowNum
      from [Members-Description-Tbl]
     ) As People
Where [User-Id] = (select [Resume-Owner-Id]
                   from [Resume-Tbl]
                  ) AND
      RowNum between @StartRowIndex+1 and @MaxRows
```

Such a query could get many errors -- variables could be undefined, tables not present, columns not defined.

One potential error that stands out is the `=` in the `where` clause.  If the subquery returns more than one row, it will generate an error.  The simple solution is to use `in` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer Gordon Linoffred.

Thanks for your answer Pradeep.

That's right. Your answers are right. But my query rise previous error again. I read my query again and understand that I must write `[People].RowNum` or `RowNum` instead of `[User-Id]`. This works now. Thanks again. :)